# Did the early early universe make matter by breaking the vacuum?

Tags: particle-physics, cosmology, laser

Let me give some background before asking the question which is the last sentence .Article in Science Magazine  says " Physicists are planning to build lasers so powerful they could rip apart empty space".  I am not a physicist that is why I post the question so i can get expert advice.

If I read it right they are creating matter from the vacuum with energetic collision of photons. What is know as "breaking the vacuum". Apparently this is common knowledge that has been around since being  theorized in 1930.  I seem not to be having any luck finding anything.

The article says this is the reverse of what we do when we get energy from fission or fusion

Being puzzled I read articles on "Where matter comes from in the early universe" , I figured E=MC^2 had to be running in reverse then. The article said  the energy is so high that the "bosons" can decay into all the observable particles depending on the energy you begin with.  Which I assume is the negative gravitational potential that inflationary cosmology speaks of.

My question: Is a broken vacuum what sprang forth the matter in the early universe or is this an unrelated consequence of some other physical law or laws?

Comment: "Breaking the vacuum" or "ripping apart empty space" are just metaphors that you should not take too close to heart. Ultimately matter and energy are the same thing. Colliding powerful laser beams may (or may not) be a way of converting the energy of photons into the energy of other particles. This has nothing to do with creating matter from nothing, because the total energy (and therefore matter) remains the same per the energy conservation law. Aside from both being quantum processes with some similarity, this has nothing to do with the creation of matter from nothing in the early universe.

Comment: The energy conservation law states that energy remains the same in uniform time. The opposite is also true, if time is not uniform, energy will change accordingly. There was no time before the Big Bang when time started, so time was not uniform. It wasn't there and then it was. Accordingly, energy also changed from nothing to the full energy of the universe at the instant when time started. Energy and time are two sides of the same existence. No time - no energy, but the creation of time automatically creates energy, because time and energy are two sides of the same thing (Fourier conjugates).

Comment: ...that makes sense and you explanation is well put.  I was hoping you would not mind telling me ....( although a different question )   ...how do scientists explain the "negative potential energy" so the conservation of matter and energy are not violated in the early universe...that's always mystified me.    Otherwise I will close the question, you seemed to have explained it.

Comment: I can try explaining on an example of a star, but applying it to the early universe is dependent on the cosmological model and the conventional Friedmann model is not my favorite :) Same as in electricity, potential in itself is meaningless. Birds sitting on an electrical wire couldn't care less what its potential is. Only the difference between two potentials matters. The potential gravitational energy is a difference between two potentials at different distances from a star. What distance should we take as the baseline? Well, no particular one is better than any other, except for infinity.

Comment: The potential at the infinity is maximal, but what arbitrary number should we assign to it? No particular number is better that any other, except for zero. So we just set the baseline of the gravitational potential as zero at infinity. Because the potential at any closer distance is smaller, the potential energy there is "negative", but this is simply a result of our choice of the baseline. It does not mean that "negative energy" actually exists. The "negative potential energy" simply means that we are subtracting a certain amount from the total energy, but the result is always positive.